# php possible attack?

Tags: php, security, xss

i would like to now if i am on any kind of attack and what security should be applied.

I got this in my server logs:

> "GET /site.php?a={%24{passthru%28chr%28105%29.chr%28100%29%29}} HTTP/1.1" 404 214 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
>
> /?file=../../../../../../proc/self/environ%00 HTTP/1.1" 400 227 "-" ""
>
> /stats/awstats.pl?configdir=|echo;echo%20YYYAAZ;uname;id;echo%20YYY;echo| HTTP/1.1" 404 222 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0"

Can you please help me and explain what can it be? Should i worry? Any additional information will be appreciated.

Comment: This question should go on serverfault.com ?

Comment: may be better asked on `serverfault`

Comment: (404=not found)=safe (400=Bad Request)=safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as an attempted attack, yes. Depending on your application, it's hard to tell you what you should do, as we have no idea what you have already done.

But one thing is certain, **always** validate your user input. Assuming you're using the `GET` variables in your application, here's a  few things to keep in mind

- Depending on what `$_GET['a']` should contain, always make sure it *does* contain that (and only that) before processing it. This includes making sure it's a number (`is_numeric`) or that it matches a specific pattern (regex), length or some other predefined criteria.
- Regarding `$_GET['file']` - if you have a script that serves files based on `$_GET['file']`, make sure you only include files in your current directory. That means, disallow slashes `/` and dotdot's `..`.
- Last, again, validate your input, but assuming you don't use `eval()` or have any other user input executed, you seem safe.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the contents of:

`index.php` (or your `/` (root) handler)
`awstats.pl` and
`site.php`

are.

These are fairly common SQL injection (and other) attacks that may (or may not) compromise the data in your database or files on your server.

**It depends on how your scripts handle this input**.

Answer (score 0):

You should worry if you have unsafe code, such as `eval()` and non-static includes (`include $name;`). Always avoid those coding styles.

You should also worry if there's software on your server which is outdated.